# Variable (that contains a space) in a Python subprocess command

Tags: python, subprocess

I am having a problem using a path variable (that contains a space) in a Python subprocess command.

[image]

This should be so simple, yet I have wasted almost 3 hours trying to get the full value to work?

HELP!

Comment: The python code is doing its job: Running a shell with the command you give it. It's simply your shell who doesn't parse spaces natively, so you should do it instead.

Comment: Why do you run this with the shell in the first place?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I need to have shell=true so I can gracefully handle the error in Python (as its all in the same shell).  By not having, Python just barfs out an error and there is no graceful error handling.

Comment: You can catch the error in python via try/except if you don't use a shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change repo to:

```
repo='/Users/derekm/"BGGoPlan Home"/"99.0 Repo"/Response/response-dashboard'
```

That should fix your issue.

If you'd like to programmatically solve this issue then I recommend doing the following:

```
repo_loc = repo_loc.replace(" ", "\ ")
```

Just before your `sp2 = ...` line.

Comment: Hi scr. thanks for your help.  You got me 75% there :)  What if I move the variable to an ENV file though?  See my new update

Comment: Hey Derek, I do not see your new update. Can you double check for me?

Comment: Yes.  Updated now

Comment: any ideas on how to programmatically add the double quotes?

Comment: Yes but there's a faster solution, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Note that while this fixes the very specific issue, it is generally better to use an actual shell escape function like `shlex.quote`.